# How to copy Flask Python Artifacts files to Windows Server using DEVOPS Pipelines

Tags: python, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline for Python Flask Project which have two stages. 1st is build and Test and other is deployment.

In Deployment Stage I want to copy artifacts files to my Remote Windows Server which can be only accessed by IP with Port. How can I do it?

I have tried few things

1. Window Machine File Copy. But it says cannot parse URL

   ```
        inputs:
          SourcePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/flask-files.zip'
          MachineNames: 'IP:Port'  # Replace with the name or IP address of your Windows Server
          AdminUserName: 'username'  # Replace with the admin username to access the Windows Server
          AdminPassword: 'password'  # Replace with the admin password to access the Windows Server
          TargetPath: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sampletransfer'
        displayName: 'Copy Artifact to Windows Server'
   ```
2. PowerShell@2

```
         displayName: 'Copy artifact to remote server'
         inputs:
           targetType: 'filePath'
           filePath: 'copy-artifact.ps1'
           arguments: '-ArtifactStagingDirectory "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
```

**.ps1 file has this code**

```
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$ArtifactStagingDirectory
)

$sourcePath = Join-Path -Path $ArtifactStagingDirectory -ChildPath "flask-files.zip"
$targetPath = "\\myip:port\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\sampletransfer"
$adminUsername = "myuser"
$adminPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($adminUsername, $adminPassword)

Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath -Destination $targetPath -ToSession (New-PSSession -ComputerName myip -Port myport-Credential $credentials)
```

**But its giving me this error**

````
The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client 
computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the 
TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts 
list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help ```
````

Comment: I'd use something like ansible for this https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_winrm.html ; you'll need to configure winrm on the host

Answer (score 0):

In this sort of situation you should perhaps take a step back and get outside the box. Approaches you can take, and I have done similar at times

1. Set up an SFTP server - and push the deployable artifacts over the wire through SFTP. This may be an older kind of approach - but it works
2. Set up and run a daemon that will pull the built artifact from another location. This decouples the solution.
3. Another approach would be to build a reset service that you can bundle and push the package

Moreover, if you are running docker on that Windows Server - and maybe minikube, you can take advantage of more modern tooling and pull from package repositories.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error here: `targetPath = "\\myip:port\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\sampletransfer"` you probably meant `$myip:$port`.

Apart from that I don't understand why you are copying the file to an UNC path (to a Remote Server) but are combining that with PowerShell remoting. So effectively you are trying to copy **from** the remote server **to** the remote server. But the source file is not on the remote server.

If you can reach the remote server over the network (by ip) there's no need for PowerShell remoting. Also, a UNC path doesn't take a port number so use `targetPath = "\\$myip\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\sampletransfer"`

Since you are using an [administrative share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share) (c$) you'll need administrator rights on the remote machine. A better alternative might be to create a share on the remote machine to copy to.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. The remote server I have can only be accessed by Specific Port with IP. So in this case what would be the better solution that you suggest? Also can you provide any pipeline yaml task code for this?

Comment: SMB has a fixed port so you can never do a copy using a randomly available port number.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the server can only be accessed on a specific IP or port, is this for inbound traffic? Can the server "see" the Azure DevOps instance? (the internet for Azure DevOps Services, or your on prem Azure DevOps Server)

If so then you could use an [environment agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) running on the target machine. This can then run tasks defined in your pipeline and can download the package directly from Azure DevOps and run the appropriate tasks to unzip / copy the files / configure the web server etc.

If you do this then you would

1. create an Environment in Azure DevOps.
2. deploy the agent to the target machine and configure it to be bound to the environment
3. update your build job to publish the zip file as a "pipeline artifact"
4. change the job in your second stage to be a "Deployment" rather than a "job" and set that to use the appropriate environment.
5. add a task to your deployment to download the pipeline artifact
6. unzip the artifact
7. copy the files to the appropriate path

If you do this you will get additional benefits such as being able to see the deployment history for all machines in an environment, and being able to create  an approval process so that your pipeline will notify specific people that a deployment is available to run, which they can then authorise in the Azure DevOps UI